# Creating extra content areas

Tags: template, ee-1.13

I created a new template file (my-page.phtml) on /app/design/frontend/pkgName/themeName/template/page.

I'm aware of how the `content`, `footer` and other blocks are declared an what happens when `getChildHtml()` is called.

One thing I've been unable to wrap my head around is how do I create extra content areas (with different names) since I want to have, for example, /sales/orders/history, /customer/account/edit and other blocks to show on the same page but in a different areas (the commented out code in my template), so that I can style everything like I want in its own place within my intended layout (almost like a two column layout)

This template has the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
         <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
    </head>
    <body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?'  class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
        <div class="container ">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
            <div class="row main-container">
                <div class="row main-container col2-left-layout">

                    <div class="sidebar col-left col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-main col-md-8">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- order history here before the footer -->
            <!--
            <div class="col-md-12 sales_history">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sales_history') ?>
            </div>
            -->
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I create extra content areas with different names? On pages.xml?

Comment: It depends where are you are trying to render this template file? If it is in customer dashboard then should you check in `customer.xml`.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You say I should create a block handle (like content, for example) in my `customer.xml` and I can just start using it right away? (assuming my other xml are well configured)